# Resize container DIV to fit element height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on this [page](http://ismaelcala.com/) and I'm having a issue with the DIV where sliders are. This `div#home-slider` has a `height: 350px` as you may notice and it works fine for large resolutions but since the page is responsive, when I resize the window or see the page from a tablet or smartphone a white row appears just below the sliders and it's caused by the height value since it doesn't change. Can any give me a solution for change the height or tell me if there is a CSS solution or hack for this? What would yours do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the height to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the height declaration.

Comment: If I do that then the menu fails since all the time it get sticky to the top